# how to assert values inside "render" in unit test case (grails ,junit)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit

I was trying to assert the values inside "render" in my unit test cases written in Grails. But it does not seems to be proper

```
   render(view:"create",model[:])
```

what i tried was
       assertEquals("create",renderArgs("view"))

i also tried some alternatives like controller.response.renderedUrl etc. But none of those are working.
Could someone give an idea?

Thanks in advance,
BK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tests work:

grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy:

```
package demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        render view: 'first'
    }
}
```

test/unit/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy:

```
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test render view"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        '/demo/first' == view
    }
}
```

test/unit/demo/DemoControllerTests.groovy:

```
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(DemoController)
class DemoControllerTests {

    void testRenderView() {
        controller.index()
        assert '/demo/first' == view
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To test the view you can simply use an implicit `view` variable, though it will point to the path of your view/template, e.g. `/controller/create`. So you could write `assertEquals(view, '/controller/create')`. There is also an implicit `model` variable for which you can proceed similarly.

See [docs](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.4/guide/testing) (*Testing View Rendering* section).